# Is there a way where i can put my selected entry from the grid panel to a field label using extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs5

I am trying to view the selected entry from the grid panel into the textfield box.The textfield box is in some other file and the code to select the entry are in other file.

```
{ 
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'file',
    fieldLabel: 'type',
    id: 'type',
    labelWidth: 50,
    msgTarget: 'side',
    allowBlank: false,
    anchor: '100%',
}
```

this is generating a text field of field "type".How should i get the selected value in the grid to the textfield type

Comment: Can you also post the code.

Comment: this is one file where the selection is happening:-    var record=this.areaFilters.get("selectedArea")

        alert(record[0].get("type"));
        alert(record[0].get("code"));
        alert(record[0].get("name"));
        //newUrl = this.url + record[0].get("spaAgreementId");
        if(record[0].get("type")!=null) {
            //alert(record[0].get("updateTypeEntry"));
            this.selectedAreaEntry.add(record);

Comment: the second one- this is the field file which has the fields in it .the text box needs to be filled by the selected entries in the grid panel:- items: [{

                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'file',
                fieldLabel: 'code',
                id: 'code',
                minLength:2,
                maxLength: 3,
                labelWidth: 50,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                allowBlank: false,
                anchor: '100%',
            },

Comment: @AyushiGarg What is your ExtJS version (4, 4.2 or 5)? Thanks.

Comment: @AyushiGarg... you need to use code tags around posted code or provide sencha  fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with or without a form, but i  agree forms make  things easier

check out this fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/31le

hint: try to not use using id:'type' configs is dangerous as you can only have on id with that name in the WHOLE application, you should be using itemId:'type' which you can find

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly but you have a grid and want to display the record in another component?
I did something similar for another question but I think this might work for you aswell.

If you happen to have a grid and you want to display the selected record, you should wrap your fields inside a Ext.form.Panel (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html).

Now you have 2 components. A grid and a form panel. Now when you select a record inside a grid you can search for your Ext.form.Panel (Or create it inside an Ext.window.Window to display it on the fly) and use the loadRecord method from the Ext.form.Panel to display your data inside it.

Here is a working example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31fr